# Question about deleting a pointer. Which class should it be deleted from?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two four classes:

- **MainClass** (class where things start)
- **XmlReader** (class used to parse an xml file)
- **SerialPortSettings** (holds info about the serial port read from the xml-file, e.g. baud rate, comport etc)
- **SerialPortListener** (takes a reference to a SerialPortSettings object in its constructor)

**MainClass** has a method to read things from an xml-file.
In this method, it first creates an instance of **XmlReader** and gives it an xml-file as a constructor parameter. This xmlReader does only need to exist within this method:

```
XmlReader xmlReader (xmlFile);
```

The xmlReader parsers the xmlFile. **MainClass** gets access the xml-stuff by calling get-methods in **XmlReader**. So far everything is good.

However, one of the methods **XmlReader** offers, is a method which creates an object of type **SerialPortSettings** based on the information read from the xml-file:

```
SerialPortSettings* XmlReader::getSerialPortSettings() {
  .... // reading stuff from xml file
  return new SerialPortSettings(baudRate, dataBits, comport);
}
```

This method is called from **MainClass** and the return value is stored in a pointer:

```
SerialPortSettings* settings = xmlReader.getSerialPortSettings();
```

The next thing the MainClass does is to create a **SerialPortListener** (which is a member-variable that has to exist until MainClass is exited). SerialPortListener takes a reference to a SerialPortSettings in it's constructor:

```
m_serialPortListener = new SerialPortListener(*settings);
```

Hence SerialPortSettings also has to exist until MainClass exits, therefore I have created this as a pointer.

So here is the clue:

In the **SerialPortListener** destructor I tried to delete the **SerialPortSettings**-object:

```
SerialPortListener::~SerialPortListener() {
  delete &m_settings;
}
```

Then in the **MainClass** destructor I deleted the **SerialPortListener**-object:

```
MainClass::~MainClass() {
  delete m_serialPortListener;
}
```

This fails. I get an error saying that I deleted something twice in the main-class:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./ioserver: double free or corruption (out): 0x00860d80 ***
```

When I remove the delete &m_settings from SerialPortListener, it works fine.
But when should pointer be deleted? What is the correct thing to do? I really want my xml-reader to create the SerialPortSettings - object, insted of returning all of the info (baud rate, comport etc) to MainClass and create the SerialPortSettings object itself.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to simply let `xmlReader::getSerialPortSettings` return a `SerialPortSettings` by value.

Let the compiler do the optimization.

But where you do need to handle pointer lifetimes, do use *smart pointers*, such as `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`. The key idea is to define ownership. The owner (which in the case of `boost::shared_ptr` is the collection of smart pointers referring to the object) is responsible for deleting – no-one else.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

The pointer should be deleted at the end of MainClass.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense (to me, at least) to use `delete` on a reference.

It would be way cleaner to not have the XML reader create new objects; treat SerialPortSettings as a "dumb" container, and just pass in a reference to fill in with data from the XML:

```
XmlReader::getSerialPortSettings(SerialPortSettings& settings);
```

the actual instance can then be a local variable in the main program, and be passed (by const reference, this time) to the serial port when it's created:

```
SerialPortSettings portSettings;
m_xmlReader->getSerialPortSettings(portSettings);
m_serialPort = new SerialPort(portSettings);
```

the life time of the settings instance is then naturally the same as the scope it's in, since it's just a local variable.

If the method in the main class that reads XML needs to exit before the serial port goes out of scope, you could make the settings a member variable of the main class, instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of m_settings? Is it a SerialPortSettings* or a SerialPortSettings? If the latter, you can't delete it like that anyway, as it's allocated on the stack. If it's the former (a pointer), you do not need the reference operator. Simply write `delete m_settings;`

Comment: The datatype og m_settings is not a pointer (no asterisk). In serialportlistener.h I have defined it like this: SerialPortSettings m_settings;

Comment: Just noticed this line: m_serialPortListener = new SerialPortListener(*settings);
You should delete settings; after this line, assuming you're copying its contents in SerialPortListener().

Answer (score 0):

A simple typo in your delete:

```
delete &m_settings;
```

should be:

```
delete m_settings;
```

For any pointer you should decide who `owns` the pointer, and that should be who deletes it.

Or you can use a smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` and eliminate the problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
SerialPortListener::~SerialPortListener() {
  delete &m_settings;
}
```

That block looks quite weird. Are you sure you aren't trying to delete value by reference? Cause C++ does it automatically when you delete the class, so your delete is really trying to delete twice.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all, you're missing the truly important bit of information which is HOW is SerialPortListener::m_settings being stored. Because of the error you're getting, I'm guessing you're actually storing a copy of it, which means: I bet you have something like this:

```
class SerialPortListener {
    SerialPortSettings m_settings;

    SerialPortListener(SerialPortSettings set) {
        m_settings = set;
    }
}
```

if it's something similar to this, then the listener is saving a copy of the object in it's own memory, and deleting it doesn't make sense, since it's not a pointer. Rule of thumb, never do delete &anything until you know what you're doing and realize you really need to.

In terms of "correctness", the pointer should be freed by the main class, since it was who created it. Or if you don't have any use for it in the main class, and want the listener to delete it, save a pointer instead of an object or reference in the listener.

Comment: Almost what you wrote, except the constructor for SerialPortListener has a reference-parameter of SerialPortSettings: SerialPortListener(SerialPortSettings& set) {
        m_settings = set;
    }

Comment: OK, what's important is the bit about m_settings declaration anyways. What *I* would do is to declare it a pointer and delete it where you're doing it, anyways

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making m_serialPortSettings a pointer in SerialPortListener, and deleting it from there.